# Hide some object fields before outputing?

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, dto

Is it possible to hide certain fields before outputting it?

For the sake of simplicity let's say I have `User` and `Image` one user can have multiple images.

## User

```
public class User
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Image> Images { get; set; }
}
```

## Output

```
{
    Id: "1",
    Name: "Steve"
}
```

Now I want to output `User` with images and without. Is it possible to do something like this?

`_db.Users.SingleOrDefault(x => x.Id == id).Except(x => x.Images);`

- This would be possible by adding `[JsonIgnore]` but it's not an option since I will want to output `Images` in some different request.
- This would be possible by outputting anonymous objects but it's not an option.
- This would be possible by creating DTO, but even so, how can I assign properties automatically from model to dto? Imagine that I have 30 fields, I don't want to assign them manually.

Comment: You should look at [AutoMapper](http://automapper.org/).

Comment: @Romoku from a glance looks like this is what I need. Thanks a lot, I will investigate further.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Imagine that I have 30 fields, I don't want to assign them manually.

[Automapper](http://automapper.org/) to the rescue!

> PM> Install-Package AutoMapper

DTO:

```
public class User
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Image> Images { get; set; }
}

public class UserInfo
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Code:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<User, UserInfo>();

var user = new User { Id = 1, Name = "Bob" };

var userInfo = Mapper.Map<User, UserInfo>(user);

return Json(new { userInfo });
```

Comment: This isn't dynamic enough, image more complex system with 8 variables that may or may not be shown in result.

Comment: This is only an example. Automapper has [a ton of features](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/wiki).

Answer (score 0):

I think this is also a solution which is worth your attention: You can define some `base class` or `interface` which contains elements you want, something like this:

```
public class UserBase {
  public int Id {get;set}
  public string Name {get;set;}
}
public class User : UserBase {
  public IEnumerable<Image> Images { get; set; }
}

//or using interface, I think this is better
public class IUserBase {
  int Id {get;set}
  string Name {get;set;}
}
public class User : IUserBase {
  public int Id { get; set; }
  public string Name { get; set; }
  public IEnumerable<Image> Images { get; set; }
}
```

Then in your `LINQ` query, you can do something like this:

```
var result = users.Select(x=>(IUserBase)x);
foreach(var user in result)
   System.Diagnostics.Debug.Print(user.Id + " : " + user.Name);//There is no `Images` element here except using explicitly cast to User type.
```

Comment: I think what he want is, depending on database settings choose which properties to show.